# What's the codeceptjs equivalent of expect?

Tags: codeceptjs

I'm making an API call and want to verify that it succeeded. Something like this:

```
var response = await api.ensureSettings(data);

expect(response.code).toBe(200);
```

How can I check equivalence in codeceptjs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with chai http://chaijs.com/. After install chai just do:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
```

on top of your test script, than you can use

```
expect(response.code).to.be.equal(200);
```

I recommend you use postman/newman to testing your Api, but you could do it too with codeceptjs.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use additional libraries either codeceptjs chai or codeceptjs assert library

"codeceptjs-assert": "0.0.4",
"codeceptjs-chai": "^1.0.0",

I.assertStrictEqual(response.code, 200)